# How to remove character "-" from Wordpress website name

Tags: wordpress

As shown in the first picture below, my website's name shows a "-" in the Google search results.

[image: Google Search Result]

I tried editing it on my website in the Site Identity section but the "-" is not visible in the Site Title.

[image: Site Title]

Need help in understanding where should I make the changes on the website to remove the "-".

Comment: Hi, which theme are you currently using? Normally a good place to start would be in the `header.php` file in your theme folder, but this really depends on how the theme functions are set up.

Comment: There can be too many things going on here. Number 1: What you see on Google is the <title> tag from your homepage, not necessarily your site title. So check the title page of your home page first. Number 2: you are checking Google search; an update on Google is not visible earlier than 3 days. So I would discourage to use that as your reference. Please take a look at this [snippet](https://snag.gy/nAKNLj.jpg), which is from your homepage. Somewhere in your page you have added a hyphen "-".

Comment: @Trollsyn: I'm using Olsen Light theme and could see the issue in header.php

Comment: @Taha PS. If my answer solved your problem, please accept it as a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark to the left :)

Answer (score 1):

The Olsen Light theme utilizes the `add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );` function, which is recommended for handling page/post titles. It uses the "-" separator by default.

You can try to filter this with the [`document_title_separator`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/document_title_separator/) hook to change the separator.

From the back of my head, and not tested, you can add this to the `functions.php` file in your theme folder:

```
function taha_set_document_title_separator ($sep) {
    if (empty(get_bloginfo('description'))) {
        return ('') ;
    } else {
        return ('-') ;
    }
}

add_filter ('document_title_separator', 'taha_set_document_title_separator') ;
```

What I'm trying to do is to check if your blog description is empty. If it is, then the separator symbol is just an empty space. If you have a description, then the separator would be the "-" as per default.

Hope this helps!